# Select if criteria is met

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a datatable with three columns: timestamp, curveID and price. I would like to give a time and then select for each day the timestamp, curveID and price but only if all curveIDs are present.

The problem is, not for every time all the data is present, so at 10:00:00 there might be only data for curveID 1 but nothing for ID =2, and so forth.

I thought I could do the following to select the first dataset where all curveIDs are there and time is greater or equal to my criteria:

```
        dataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\temp\Prices.xml", XmlReadMode.InferTypedSchema);
        ds = dataSet.Tables[0];
        var dt = ds.Clone();
        int criteria = 10;
        var list = ds.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp").Hour >= criteria)
                    .GroupBy(x => new{Date = x.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp").Date, Curve = x.Field<object>("CurveID")})
                    .First().ToList();
```

However, this returns multiple records on the same day (at different times) for the same curve ID. 
I would like to return only a single record  for each curveID on each day at a time close to the criteria time where all curveIDs are present.

For clarity, lets say I m looking for curveID 1 & 2, if at 10:00:00 on day 1 only curveID 1 is present but curveID 2 is missing I would need to check whether at 10:01:00 both are there, if yes I take for that day the two record sets from that time. This I would have to check for every day in the database

Comment: What would you like to have in that one record? A sum? The first? The average?

Comment: Just the value, there is only going to be one record for each combination of timestamp and curveID, so first will do

Comment: Is it correct to say that each row is defined by tuple (timestamp, curveID)? What do you mean saying "all curveIDs"? How many of them do you have?

Comment: yes a tuple, there is many but I know by what I want to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// criteria is your integer Hour representation
var criteria = 10;
// array of curveIds to look for
var curveIds = new int[] {1, 2};
var result = 
    // grouping by date first
    ds.GroupBy(x => x.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp").Date, 
        (date, items) => new { date, items = items
            // items with the same timestamp go to one group
            .GroupBy(i => i.Field<DateTime>("Timestamp"), (datetime, timestampItems) => new { datetime, timestampItems })
            // filter by criteria
            .Where(dti => dti.datetime.Hour >= criteria)
            // filter by curveIds
            .Where(dti => curveIds.All(cid => dti.timestampItems.Any(tsi => tsi.Field<int>("curveID") == cid)))
            .OrderBy(dti => dti.datetime)
            .FirstOrDefault() });
```

In the end you will receive a "per day" result fitting all your mentioned requirements: occurs after some *criteria*, have all `curveIds`, be earliest one.

Comment: are you missing some brackets?

Comment: @nik, let me know if you've got any problems running the code.

Comment: sorry I was off the desk for a few minutes. I get lots of errors (Invalid anonymous type member declaration and a few others) let me try to work through it

Comment: @nik, fixed missing `new` keyword.

Comment: I still get an anonymous type error on this => new { date, items items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106171/discussion-between-ivan-gritsenko-and-nik).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to group by Date first and then by hour using something like

```
group thing by new {
   firstThing = x.Field<DateTime>("TimeStamp").Date, 
   secondThing = x.Field<DateTime>("TimeStamp").Date.Hour, 
}
```

My syntax is probably off by a little, but that should get you moving in the right direction

Comment: thanks pedro. But I dont think this helps much because I have minute data, and if I group by minute I still dont know how to iterate over the data to select a minute where all IDs I want are present